# Python to Visio Syntax for Transparency

Tags: python, vba, winapi, visio, win32com

I am trying to change the transparency of a shape in Visio using python, but am not having any luck. If anyone knows how to set the transparency in python, please let me know!!

[How to change Visio font name and color using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343086/how-to-change-visio-font-name-and-color-using-python?rq=1)

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import constants as vis
app = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch( 'Visio.Application' )
shape = app.ActivePage.DrawRectangle(5,5,6,6)

shape.Cells( 'Fillforegnd' ).FormulaU = 'RGB(112,255,141)'

shape.Cells('Transparency').FormulaU = '0.25'
```

This does not work either, and provides the same outcome as above:

```
shape.Cells('Transparency').FormulaU = '25%'
```

The outcome in Visio is a rectangle of the correct size and color, just not the correct transparency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transparency setting is a percentage, so you want to set the cell to '25%'.

Comment: This does not work either. It gives the same output as before

Comment: Have you checked the value set in the shape's shapesheet?

Comment: I just did, and it turns out I was using the wrong name for transparency, it is actually "FillforegndTrans" . It works now! Thank you so much for your help, I never would've thought to look there.